Accessing Base index.html file through localhost (using php)
I'm trying to run some files through localhost using php. I've been running into some problems with running it, so I wanted to make sure I could run the base index.html file installed on the computer and then link my localhost to the appropriate directory.
I first found my Document Root in httpd.conf in /private/etc/apache2, which was "/Library/WebServer/Documents".
Then, I checked that folder, where I found a file (index.html.en) with the following code:
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>

However, when trying to access it through terminal with the following command, I got the following error after lookign up http://localhost:8080/index.html:
(base) Max@macbook-pro-6 ~ % php -S localhost:8080

Not Found
The requested resource / was not found on this server.
The same result also occured with the following command, accessing through the Documents folder:
(base) Max@macbook-pro-6 Documents % php -S localhost:8080

How would I resolve this error, and then how would I change the root to point from /Library/WebServer/Documents to my desired php project?

php -S doesn't use the Apache configuration.

My apologies, removed the tag. Just checking, but am I correct to be looking in the /private/etc/apache2 folder?

Stop using the PHP built-in  webserver (i.e. php -S), and actually serve and access the site through Apache, if that's what you want to use. Assuming Apache is running, it's probably accessible at http://localhost

I'm ok with accessing the site through either Apache or the default server (I'm not super familiar with the difference honestly), but I just need a means of accessing the files on my computer. Right now, typing http://localhost or http://http://localhost/index.html gives me a 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource error.

That just means the apache account doesn't have permission to read the file. On many Linux systems it's the www-data or similar account which Apache runs as. For Mac you might have to check, I'm not a Mac user

Ok, I checked this post, which suggested I check the User and Group, both of which were _www as desired. Not sure what else to do?

Did you actually verify that those are the correct values for your setup specifically? Is that the permission on the index file itself, or just the folder

Those are the values I found in the httpd.conf file - is that where my setup is or is there another file I should check?

OK.. and the index file definitely has got that user and/or group having read permissions on it?

The index file is just the one line of code - I'm not sure where I would find the permissions?

Just the normal operating system file permissions. Not sure where they show up on a mac, perhaps if you look for a file in Finder and check its properties?? Or I'm sure you can at least check them on the command line, maybe ls -la or similar to list all items in the folder? If not, I'm sure Google will know how

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1203/mac
